# Point at Infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, infinity

I started to take an introduction to complex analysis course, we learned open and closed regions in the complex plane, but our professor told us that the whole complex plane is open and closed at the same time. It's closed because of the "point at infinity", but what is the point at infinity?

Comment: What is your definition of "open" and of "closed"? (topologically, regarding a specific metric, or something else?)

Comment: closed region if it contains all of its boundary points, and open if every point has a neighborhood inside that region

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257954/extended-complex-plane-and-infinity)

Comment: You did not answer the question asked by user1729. With one definition, if $X$ is a topological space, then $X$ is automatically open and closed. There is nothing to prove here.

Comment: Maybe "open and compact" is what was intended? Of course, "open" when considering $\mathbb C$ and "compact" when considering ${\mathbb C} \cup \{\infty\}.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: @NoName you should edit your question to clarify this.